Why do I keep getting logged out from Stack Overflow?
I don't know what is going on with the Stack Overflow website. 
Every day I open the website, my user account is logged out.
It is very annoying and frustrating behavior to log in again and again.
The logging session should be at least for a year.
Chrome version: 125.0.6422.77

have you set cookies to be deleted when you shut down the browser?

No, I didn't do such kind of settings. Even I sometimes didn't close the browser. but still, my account is getting logged out.

Well that is something on your end, otherwise we would be seeing much more such reports. It can be anything, from adblocker, through antivirus software to the ISP changing IP and causing the logout. We really can't know.

Do you use any RSS feeds? IIRC, there's an issue with those which results in logging you out. However, I'd suggest doing a search here on MSE or on MSO to find the existing questions about the issue to see if there's been any action on it.
